# open a customer record in Microsoft Dynamic from outside

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am new to Microsoft Dynamic CRM.

I have a .NET Winforms application which requires to open a customer record in Microsoft Dynamic CRM. I have no idea how to do this.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'open' ? Display the data of the customer in your application or open a browser window opened with the specific customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get information of the customer in your winform application there is actually two ways of doing that, by going to the SQL server database directly and query filtered views, or by going through webservices.

If you want to open a customer record, simply get the GUID the same way, and open the page

```
/OrganizationName/sfa/accts/edit.aspx?id=The Guid of the Account
```

for Account, and

```
/OrganizationName/sfa/conts/edit.aspx?id=The Guid of the Contact
```

for Contacts.

For more information on querying filtered views, check out [Filtered View Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151204.aspx) and for webservices

- to use webservices [CrmService Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151175.aspx)
- to query a record check [Use Condition Operators in a Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151203.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

fyi: see also [URL Addressable Forms and Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx)